# This car is *a great speed*

Tags: grammar, nouns

I encounter this expressions that stand for physical entities. But for example, *speed* is not a thing, it is a *property* that a thing can have, so how can *a car* be *a great speed*? I'm looking for grammatical insights and justifications.

> This concession is not *a public information*.
>
> This car is *a great speed*.
>
> This book is *a long read*.
>
> The quiz is *a multiple choice*.

Comment: I would say *This concession is not public information*, *This car has great speed*, *This book is a long read*, and *The quiz is multiple choice*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. "This car has great speed" sounds odd to me too, unless the car is currently traveling at a great (as in, high) speed.  While not what the OP is going for, "This car is very fast" or similar would be preferable I think.

Comment: @Doc Agreed. *This car is very fast* is more to the point. However, I think we can say *this person has great speed*, *that ship has great speed*, and so on. I've never heard such use with a car before, but if a ship can have great speed, I believe we could say that to a car too, perhaps. Don't you think so?

Comment: No, a car can't be a great speed.

Comment: Of the four examples you've provided, I only find two of them (the last two) to be acceptable English. The first two are way off: _This car **has** great speed,_ or, _This car **is very fast**,_ and, _This concession is not public information_.

Comment: @J.R. I'm even a bit skeptical of the last one. I can stretch it to assume that "quiz" is elided at the end of the sentence, but it definitely reads oddly to me. I'd definitely say "The quiz is multiple choice." or "It is a multiple choice quiz." If you change "multiple choice" to "short answer", the oddness might stand out better: "The quiz is a short answer." Just *one* short answer? Probably not. (Also the *quiz* is the *question* part, not the *answer* part (or type of answer)). Graduate, can you tell us where you have seen sentences like these?

Comment: Pardon my language but I have heard an offensive phrase "She is a great f***." Maybe, it's used as a *predicate noun* ending the sentence. This may simply mean that the *car has great speed* emphasizing the speed of the car.

Comment: COCA gives reference of using *She is a beauty.*

Comment: @Wendi - I agree with all of that, and had that same thought about it being elided.

Comment: @MaulikV *Beauty* can be a noun that describes a person (ex. "Beauty and the Beast".) "Speed" can't. "She is a speed" doesn't make any sense. That's the difference.

Comment: @WendiKidd Why cannot 'speed' be a noun? Though not in this context but to prove 'speed' a noun - *The project advanced with gratifying speed.*

Comment: @MaulikV *Speed* is a common noun--it's the 1394th most common word in COCA's frequency list.  However, the noun *speed* can't be used in constructions like "This car is a great speed".

Comment: "A need for speed" would carry the implication that speed can be a thing. There is something to be said for categories. "This book is a long read" is a caution that the book may take a great deal of time to finish reading and isn't that unusual to my mind. "The quiz is multiple choice" is also a reference to a category as there are other possibilities like short answer and essay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This concession is not a public information**. - Is inaccurate as the definition of "concession" in the sentence would not be a public agreement. Therefore it doesn't require the article "a" to modify it.

**This car is a great speed**. - Is grammatically incorrect. The "car" is a noun that cannot be grammatically modified by the word "speed." The sentence is poorly formed and it would require complete restructuring to make sense.

**This book is a long read**. This sentence is grammatically correct. "Read" modifies the noun book and long is at the correct adjective for this sentence.

**The quiz is a multiple choice**. Is grammatically incorrect. There is no need for the article "a" to modify "multiple choice". The correct sentence would read: The quiz is multiple choice."

Comment: Note that you can say "This car is a great drive", though.

Comment: You could. But that resembles a literary construction more than it does spoken English. "This car drives great" flows more smoothly and would still be grammatically correct.

Comment: It's not clear why "a" is not required in the first example (about concession).